# C++ string appending problems

Tags: c++, arrays, string, append

I'm having some issues right now, attempting to append a char array onto a c++ string after setting some of the values of the c++ string, and I don't see why. I was wondering if any of you know what's going.

Here's the code I'm trying to run:

```
string test = "";
test.resize(1000);
char sample[10] = { "Hello!" };
test[0] = '1';
test[1] = '2';
test[2] = '3';
test[3] = '4';
test += sample;
```

Running it through a debugger, it seems that `test` is just "1234", and the "Hello" is never added.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I dont see any thing wrong in your program and your data. Are you sure this is the sample data that you tried? or did you have any '\0' before the "Hello!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is added, but after the 1000 characters you already have in the string (4 of them are the 1234, and 996 are '\0' characters)`.

The resize function does allocate 1000 characters for the string object, but also sets the length to 1000. That's why sometimes what you want to do instead is use `reserve`

This is normally what I would do:

```
string test = "";
test.reserve(1000); // length still 0, capacity: 1000
char sample[10] = { "Hello!" };
test.push_back('1'); // length is 1
test.push_back('2'); // length is 2
test.push_back('3'); // length is 3
test.push_back('4'); // length is 4
test += sample; // length is now 10
```

Or if you want to do it your way:

```
string test = "";
test.resize(1000); // length is 1000
char sample[10] = { "Hello!" };
test[0] = '1'; // length is 1000
test[1] = '2'; // length is 1000
test[2] = '3'; // length is 1000
test[3] = '4'; // length is 1000
test.resize(4); // length is now 4, but the internal buffer still has a capacity of 1000 characters
test += sample; // length is now 10
```

Comment: It would be correct, but there's a _small_ detail you overlooked. Not 996 spaces, but 996 `'\0'` symbols. Which get treated as string terminator, when printing it.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I actually realized that a few seconds before I saw your comment, I normally resize string objects with the second parameter set to space (' ')

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is when you did `test.resize(1000)` it added `1000` *null characters* (`'\0'`) to the string. The debugger probably sees null characters as *end-of-string* markers. So any text added *after* those null characters won't get displayed.

Say text equals this (`'_'` = *null character* end of line marker):

```
test = "1234_______________Hello!"; 
            ^
            Debugger thinks text ends here
```